# Passing parameter in docker build command with fish

Tags: bash, shell, docker, parameters, fish

Using Docker For Mac, fish shell, macOS 10.11

I am trying to run the following command: `docker run -d -it --name=my-app-container -v $(pwd):/app -p 3000:3000 myapp`

I get the following error:

```
$(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(pwd)'.
fish: docker run -d -it --name=my-app-container -v $(pwd):/app -p 3000:3000 myapp
```

Been reading through repos and SO answers but cant get this to work. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: can you post `echo $(pwd)` so we can check the value

Comment: echo $(pwd) doesnt work in fish terminal. In bash, you get the pwd. ```bash-3.2$ echo $(pwd)
/Users/klik/Desktop/dckr-bwsr```

Comment: according to https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#prompt_pwd it should be `echo $PWD`

Comment: `klik@klik ~/D/dckr-bwsr> echo $PWD                                      10:48:19
/Users/klik/Desktop/dckr-bwsr`. So how do we pass this into the docker run command in fish?

Comment: what is the string you want to pass?

Comment: the string in the original post. Following your suggestion, seems like this doesnt throw an error....`docker run -d -it --name=my-app-cont -v $PWD:/app -p 3000:3000 myapp`. so switching $(pwd) to $PWD gets past this error. Now lets see if updates to index.html show on reloading...Thanks @user2915097

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent of bash `$(command)` in fish is just `(command)`

So all you need to do is remove the dollar sign.

```
docker run -d -it --name=my-app-cont -v (pwd):/app -p 3000:3000 myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @user2915097 's suggestion, seems like this doesn't throw an error....`docker run -d -it --name=my-app-cont -v $PWD:/app -p 3000:3000 myapp`. So switching $(pwd) to $PWD gets past this error.